# LINQ How to take one record and skip rest c#

Tags: c#, linq

i tried to take one record and skip rest other. my code does not throw any error but does not give any output. here is my code. so please have a look and tell me what is wrong in my code.

```
public sealed class Person
{
    public Person() { }
    public Person(string name,bool HQ) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.HQ = HQ;
    }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }

    private bool _HQ;
    public bool HQ
    {
        get { return _HQ; }
        set { _HQ = value; }
    }
}

  protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name",typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("HQ", typeof(bool));

        DataRow dr = null;
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Name"]="Arijit";
        dr["HQ"]=true;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "Dibyendu";
        dr["HQ"] = false;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "Tridip";
        dr["HQ"] = false;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);


        List<Person> oPerson1 = (from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
            select new Person
            {
                Name = c.Field<string>("Name"),
                HQ = c.Field<bool>("HQ")
            }).Skip(1).Take(2).ToList();


        List<Person> oPerson2 = (from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
            select new Person
            {
                Name = c.Field<string>("Name"),
                HQ = c.Field<bool>("HQ")
            }).Take(1).Skip(2).ToList();

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code.

```
Person oPerson1 = (from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
select new Person
{
    Name = c.Field<string>("Name"),
    HQ = c.Field<bool>("HQ")
}).First(); //first person in a list


Person oPerson2 = (from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
select new Person
{
    Name = c.Field<string>("Name"),
    HQ = c.Field<bool>("HQ")
}).Skip(1).First(); //second person in a list

However this code can be rewritten to be clearer:

List<Person> persons = from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
select new Person
{
    Name = c.Field<string>("Name"),
    HQ = c.Field<bool>("HQ")
};

Person oPerson1 = persons[0];
Person oPerson2 = persons[1];
```

Answer (score 9):

if you want to take first record you can call these `Take(1)` , `First()` , `FirstOrDefault()`

if you want to take 1 record in the middle call this : `Skip(n).Take(1)` where `n` - is number of skipped records

When you call `Take(n)` - no need to call Skip after that, it have already selected n records

Comment: Important distinction.  `Take` returns an `IEnumerable<TSource>` and `First` returns `TSource`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "take one and skip the rest", but I suspect you're confusing how the LINQ operations work. They return a **new** sequence based on the criteria you specified, and that new sequence only has exactly what you asked for.

For example, if you have a List with three items, and you called `Take(1)`, you get back an IEnumerable with 1 item. There is nothing left to "skip" because there's only one element in your list. Your original data table is left unchanged -- LINQ sequences are immutable.

It sounds like all you really want to do is:

```
    List<Person> oPerson2 = (from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
        select new Person
        {
            Name = c.Field<string>("Name"),
            HQ = c.Field<bool>("HQ")
        }).Take(1).ToList();
```

Of course, this is a very common operation in LINQ so there's another, somewhat "clearer" way to do it:

```
    Person oPerson2 = (from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
        select new Person
        {
            Name = c.Field<string>("Name"),
            HQ = c.Field<bool>("HQ")
        }).First();
```

Answer (score 3):

I preffer to use `IQueryable` rather than `List`.

Anyway you can use [Queryable.Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357513.aspx) to skip the no of elements you need

```
   IQueryable<Person> oPerson2 = (from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
            select new Person
            {
                Name = c.Field<string>("Name"),
                HQ = c.Field<bool>("HQ")
            }).Skip(2).Take(1);
```

Also you will find more about this in [Return or Skip Elements in a Sequence (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386988.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get only one record, you should replace final ToList call with `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` they are here just for this purpose.
Difference between two methods is, `First()` will throw exception if there is nothing to return (e.g. empty collection). And `FirstOrDefault()` will return `default(T)` (e.g. null for classes and 0 for value types).

Answer (score 1):

Breaking down the chaining then:

```
List<Person> oPerson2 = (from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
  select new Person
  {
    Name = c.Field<string>("Name"),
    HQ = c.Field<bool>("HQ")
  }).Take(1).Skip(2).ToList();
```

becomes:

```
var tmp0 = (from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
  select new Person
  {
    Name = c.Field<string>("Name"),
    HQ = c.Field<bool>("HQ")
  });
var tmp1 = tmp0.Take(1);
var tmp2 = tmp1.Skip(2);
List<Person> oPerson2 = tmp2.ToList();
```

This makes it easier to see the mistake. tmp0 is an enumerable that will return every possible row when enumerated. tmp1 is an enumerable that will return just the first 1 row in tmp0 (or less if there isn't enough rows). tmp2 is an enumerable that will skip the first 2 rows in tmp1 (or less if there isn't enough rows) and then return the rest. Finally oPerson2 makes these enumerables actually return their results and stores it in a list.

From this it's clear that the mistake was `.Skip(2)` because it's taking a one-element enumeration and skipping up to 2 and leaving the rest, resulting in a list of max(1 - 2, 0) = 0 elements.

Leave out the `Skip()` and you get what you want, as "take up to 1" already entails "skip the rest".

Answer (score 0):

Also .First() can be used to achive this

```
List<X> xlist= XBusiness.GetAllX(xname.ToString());
X lastX = xlist.First();
```