# Select TOP 1 for each FK in list using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a large table where I'm trying to select the `top 1` row for each FK in a list.

My table is laid out as:

```
ChangeId | AssetId | Timestamp
1          1         123
2          2         999
3          1         3478
4          3         344
5          2         1092
```

Where `ChangeId` is my `PK`, `AssetId` is my `FK` and `Timestamp` is the value I'm trying to select.

If I try the following:

```
var results =

from Asset in _context.Asset
join change in _context.Change on Asset.AssetId equals change.AssetId into potentialChange
from actualChange in potentialChange.OrderByDescending(y => y.ChangeId).Take(1)
select 
{
   AssetId,
   Timestamp
}
```

Where my expected result would be:

```
[
  {
    AssetId: 1,
    Timestamp: 3478
  },
  {
    AssetId: 2,
    Timestamp: 1092
  },
  {
    AssetId: 3,
    Timestamp: 344
  }
]
```

This query flags up the `The LINQ expression could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.` which is not suitable for a production rollout.

Running a `foreach` loop and selecting each item out 1 by 1 works, not it's not a performant solution.

Is there a suitable way to achieve the above?

Comment: Apologies I'll remove it

Comment: No worries! (Maybe you should have <sql-server>?) Or <linq>.

Comment: Instead of joining, add navigation properties on entities, and use something like `_context.Assets.SelectMany(asset=>asset.Changes.Take(1)).Select(change=>new{change.Timestamp,change.AssetId})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to group it by AssetId and take max from each group

```
var results =

from Asset in _context.Asset
join change in _context.Change on Asset.AssetId equals change.AssetId into potentialChange
group potentialChange by potentialCharge.AssetId into g
select 
{
    g.Key,
    g.Max().Timestamp
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Group By` as follows:

```
List<MyTable> data = new List<MyTable>()
{
     new MyTable(){ChangeId = 1, AssetId = 1, Timestamp = 123},
     new MyTable(){ChangeId = 2, AssetId = 2, Timestamp = 999},
     new MyTable(){ChangeId = 3, AssetId = 1, Timestamp = 123},
     new MyTable(){ChangeId = 5, AssetId = 3, Timestamp = 123},
     new MyTable(){ChangeId = 5, AssetId = 2, Timestamp = 123},
};

var expectedData = data.OrderByDescending(d => d.Timestamp).GroupBy(d => d.AssetId).Select(g => new
{
     AssetId = g.Key,
     TimeStamp = g.First().Timestamp

}).ToList();
```

This will give your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.First()` instead of `.Take(1)`

[LINQ How to take one record and skip rest c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095077/linq-how-to-take-one-record-and-skip-rest-c-sharp)

Comment: Triggers a `Type inference failed in the call to SelectMany` exception